Node.js Not Run Terminal
enter image description here Basecally my problem is i am making script.js file and create loop
loop was not run in node.js run command script.js
I am showing this  error =
PS C:\Users\kisha\OneDrive\Desktop\Banked> node script.js
node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1080
  throw err;
  ^

Error: Cannot find module 'C:\Users\kisha\OneDrive\Desktop\Banked\script.js'
    at Module._resolveFilename (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1077:15)
    at Module._load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:922:27)
    at Function.executeUserEntryPoint [as runMain] (node:internal/modules/run_main:81:12)
    at node:internal/main/run_main_module:23:47 {
  code: 'MODULE_NOT_FOUND',
  requireStack: []
}

Node.js v18.17.1
PS C:\Users\kisha\OneDrive\Desktop\Banked>


The error message is pretty clear.

So in the console you are trying to run a file called "script.js"
When looking at the provided screenshot the file is actually called "javascript.js"
